# Can't update data using Mysql and Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

i want to update my array data from table monitordata, but the data wont update i dont know where's the problem. there's no error in this code too :(

this is my controller

```
public function ubah($id) {


    $data_lama = $this->monitor_m->get($id); 
    $this->data->tglmonitor = $data_lama->tglmonitor;

    $this->data->detail = $this->monitor_m->get_record(array('monitor_data.idMonitor'=>$id),true);


    $this->template->set_judul('SMIB | Monitoring')
         ->render('monitor_edit',$this->data);  
}

public function ubahku($id) {
    $id = $this->input->post('idMonitor_data'); 

    if($this->input->post('idinven')!=NULL){
            $idMonitor = $this->input->post('idMonitor');
            $kondisi = $this->input->post('kondisi');
            $nobrg = $this->input->post('nobrg');
            $keterangan = $this->input->post('keterangan');
            $kdinven = $this->input->post('kdinven');
            $idinven = $_POST['idinven'];

            for($i = 0; $i < count($idinven); $i++){

            $data_detail = array( 
                        'idMonitor' => $this->input->post('idMonitor'),
                        'idinven'=> $idinven[$i],
                        'kdinven'=> $kdinven[$i],
                        'nobrg'=> $nobrg[$i],
                        'kondisi'=> $kondisi[$i],
                        'keterangan' => $keterangan[$i]);
            //print_r($data_detail);
            $where = array('idMonitor_data' => $id);
            $this->monitordata_m->update_by($where,$data_detail);

            }
        }                  redirect('monitorcoba');  
}
```

This is my model monitordata_m

```
class Monitordata_m extends MY_Model {

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    parent::set_table('monitor_data','idMonitor_data');
}
```

This is MY_Model model i put in core folder.

```
public function update_by($where = array(), $data = array()) {
    $this->db->where($where);
    if ($this->db->update($this->table,$data)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And this is my view

```
<?php echo form_open(site_url("monitorcoba/ubahku"),'data-ajax="false"'); ?>
<input data-theme="e" style="float: right;" data-mini="true" data-inline="false" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right" value="Simpan" type="submit" />

<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-mini="true">
<?php foreach ($detail as $items): ?>    
<div data-role="collapsible">
<?php echo form_hidden('idMonitor_data', $items['idMonitor_data'] ); ?>

<?php echo form_hidden('idMonitor', $items['idMonitor'] ); ?>
    <h4><?php echo '[ '.$items['kdinven'].' ] '.$items['namabrg'] ?> </h4>
    <?php echo form_hidden('kdinven', $items['kdinven'] ); ?>
   <?php echo form_hidden('idinven', $items['idinven'] ); ?>     
    <div data-role="controlgroup">
    <?php echo form_label ('Kondisi : ');
        echo " <select name='kondisi' data-mini='true'>

 <option value=".$items['kondisi'].">".$items['kondisi']."</option>
                    <option value=''>--Pilih--</option>
                    <option value='Baik'>Baik</option>
                    <option value='Rusak'>Rusak</option>
                    <option value='Hilang'>Hilang</option>";    
              echo "</select>";



          echo form_input('keterangan',@$keterangan,'placeholder="Masukan Keterangan Tambahan"','class="input-text"');
 ?>         
   <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

even if i use update_by it doesnt work. it's been 2 weeks and i have no clue :( i've tried all of the answer that i found in google but still.. so please help me.

[image: This is my Database profiler result]

This is the DATABASE result and POST_DATA for method ubahku
[image: This is the database result for method ubahku][image: And this is Post_data result]

Comment: Have you tried enabling the profiler so that you can see what SQL statements are being run?

Comment: @colonelclick yes i have. but i dont know what's wrong because i cant understand the report ._. sorry

Comment: first debug the flow. print value of id in controller and then in model check its value if is it correct or not

Comment: Can you add the output from the Database section of the profiler?

Comment: @colonelclick i added the database result above. you can see it now

Comment: Ok this is a start. What we really need to see is the SQL output from function ubahku. Can you comment out "redirect('monitorcoba')" and then try to submit again and show the SQL output from function ubahku?

Comment: @colonelclick i added, and i found why it wont update because the query output `where idMonitor_data = '0' ` , it should be '48' not '0' .

Comment: There must be more code that we do not see. In your update SQL we can see the first argument tries to set idMonitor_data = 48, but we do not see that in your PHP anywhere. We also see that your function ubahku expects an id parameter in the URL but your form does not seem to be passing one and this should show an error. Is this the current code you are showing us?

Comment: @colonelclick thank you so much for your answer it's really helpfull. i found the answer, i have to add "[ ]" in all of the name in html form so system will detect the input as an array. my mistake was i only use this "[ ]" for kondisi and keterangan.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry i dont know how to mark the question as closed/solved so i edited the title. maybe you can help me

Comment: @Noname You accepted your own answer, that alone informs Stack and everyone that the question has been solved. There's nothing else to do, it's all good ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- owh.. ok then. thank you :)

Comment: @Noname You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thank you so much for everyone who answer my question. so the problem was when i update the data, system only detect `"kondisi[]"` and `"keterangan[]"` as an array because i use this `"[]"` for both of it, so i just have to add `"[]"` in the end of every `name` in html form / views. so system will detect every input as an array. i hope you understand what i'm saying, sorry for my bad english. thank you this case is closed :)

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a method named `update_by`, but you are calling `$this->monitordata_m->update($id,$data_detail);`. Definitely it should not work. please call `$this->monitordata_m->update_by($id,$data_detail);` from your controller & check what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Please correction `$this->monitordata_m->update($id,$data_detail);` to `$this->monitordata_m->update_by($id,$data_detail);` because your function name is `update_by` in your `monitordata_m` model.

Secondly, in your `monitordata_m` model `update_by` function have 2 param like `$where = array()` `$data = array()`, `$where` is a `array` but you calling in controller only `$id`. Your `$id` is not array. `$where` is like that `$where = array('id' => $id) //id is where field name from db table`

So, `ubahku($id)` method in your controller call `$where` in `update_by` function:

```
$where = array('id' => $id); // 'id' means "where field name"
$this->monitordata_m->update_by($where,$data_detail);
```

Comment: still not working, i know its weird. but when i use update_by function in another function in controller it works fine.

Comment: i saw your html form. you have used form action `monitorcoba/coba`. your controller name is `monitorcoba` and method name is `coba`. Right?

Comment: and you have used a condition in `ubahku` method your controller `if($this->input->post('idinven')!=NULL){`. Tell me please where your `idinven` field in your html form?

Comment: sorry that's my typo it should be monitorcoba/ubahku. oh my god thank you so much i forgot too add `idinven`in my html form.

Comment: Now it works, but after i added it, i have another problem, i'm trying too update data for data 1(which is the first one) but the result is data 1 didnt changed, its data 5 (which is the last data) that did changed its weird. i'm trying to update data 1 not data 5. :(

Comment: sorry for my bad english, after i added `idinven` field in my html form, i tried to update my data let say i have 5 data array, now i want to change data 1 but when i clicked `Submit` button it's not data 1 that changed, but data 5 or the last data. do you know the solution ? :(

Comment: your all input field in your html form change name with array `[]` like `form_hidden('kdinven[]', $items['kdinven'] );` and `<select name='kondisi[]' data-mini='true'>` and `form_input('keterangan[]',@$keterangan,'placeholder="Masukan Keterangan Tambahan"','class="input-text"');`

Comment: and some change in your controller like : `$data_detail = array( 
                        'idMonitor' => $idMonitor[$i],
                        'idinven'=> $idinven[$i],
                        'kdinven'=> $kdinven[$i],
                        'nobrg'=> $nobrg[$i],
                        'kondisi'=> $kondisi[$i],
                        'keterangan' => $keterangan[$i]);

            $where = array('idMonitor_data' => $id[$i]);`